# Doctrine reusable Criteria in Entity and Repository with joins

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.3

I have searched for this specific issue for a long time and not sure if I have a misunderstanding in using Criteria in queries or if it is just not possible (yet?)

This is an example with only the minimum fields and conditions.

I have two Entities:

- Product

  - field: visible

  Brand

  - field: active

Within the Brand entity, I have a method 
`"getVisibleProducts()"` where I want to get all Products with 
`product.visible = 1`

And in my ProductRepository I have a method `findAllVisibleForBrand(Brand $brand)` where I want to get all Products with `product.visible = 1` AND `brand.active = 1`

So my idea for best reusability was to make a criteria for the `product.visible` value within my ProductRepository and use it for query within the repository

```
/**
 * @param Brand $brand
 *
 * @return Product[]
 */
public function findAllVisibleForBrand(Brand $brand)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('product')
        ->leftJoin('product.brand', 'brand')
        ->addCriteria(ProductRepository::createVisibleCriteria())
        ->andWhere('product.brand = :brand')
        ->setParameter('brand', $brand)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
        ;
}

/**
 * @return Criteria
 */
public static function createVisibleCriteria()
{
    return Criteria::create()
        ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq('visible', '1'))
    ;
}
```

and within my Brand entity:

```
/**
 * @return Product[]|ArrayCollection
 */
public function getVisibleProducts()
{
    return $this->getProducts()->matching(ProductRepository::createVisibleCriteria());
}
```

This is working fine and without problems.

The same idea for the BrandRepository

```
/**
 * @return Brand[]
 */
public function findAllActiveBrands()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('brand')
                ->addCriteria(BrandRepository::createActiveCriteria())
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute()
        ;
}

/**
 * @return Criteria
 */
public static function createActiveCriteria()
{
    return Criteria::create()
       ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq('active', '1'))
    ;
}
```

Now my idea was to use the Brand Active Criteria within my ProductRepository to get only Products that are visible but only IF the brand is active. So my method now looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param Brand $brand
 *
 * @return Product[]
 */
public function findAllVisibleForBrand(Brand $brand)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('product')
        ->leftJoin('product.brand', 'brand')
        ->addCriteria(BrandRepository::createActiveCriteria())  // added this line
        ->addCriteria(ProductRepository::createVisibleCriteria())
        ->andWhere('product.brand = :brand')
        ->setParameter('brand', $brand)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
        ;
}
```

by adding the brandActiveCriteria this way, I get the following error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 97 near 'active = :active': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Product has no field or association named active

The Query doctrine is building looks like this:

`SELECT product FROM 
   AppBundle\Entity\Product product 
   LEFT JOIN product.brand brand 
   WHERE 
      product.active= :active 
      AND product.visible = :visible 
      AND product.brand = :brand`

adding the table name into the criterias work for the Query within the repository but not for the query within the entity since the table alias is not the same.

Is there any chance to have the rules as criteria or in any other place without duplicating it over multiple classes?

I got the idea of using static function to create criterias from
https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/collections/criteria-collection-filtering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the alias in your criteria:

```
public static function createActiveCriteria($alias = null)
{
    return Criteria::create()
       ->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->eq(($alias ? $alias.'.' : '').'active', '1'))
    ;
}
```

And then you call your criteria like this:

```
// "brand" is the name of the given alias in leftJoin
BrandRepository::createActiveCriteria('brand');
```

So your `findAllVisibleForBrand()` method will look like this:

```
public function findAllVisibleForBrand(Brand $brand)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('product')
        ->leftJoin('product.brand', 'brand')
        ->addCriteria(BrandRepository::createActiveCriteria('brand')) // Notice the alias parameter here
        ->addCriteria(ProductRepository::createVisibleCriteria())
        ->andWhere('product.brand = :brand')
        ->setParameter('brand', $brand)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
        ;
}
```

And your DQL should be like this:

```
SELECT product FROM 
   AppBundle\Entity\Product product 
   LEFT JOIN product.brand brand 
   WHERE 
      brand.active= :active 
      AND product.visible = :visible 
      AND product.brand = :brand
```

Comment: Thanks that is working, the only disadvantage is, that I have to do this in every criteria I am using. I was hoping that I have missed something in doctrine documentation :)

Comment: You have no choice because Doctrine cannot know the name of your alias in `leftJoin`. In your example you call it "brand", but you could also just name it "b" or whatever else, so you have to explicitly name it in the criteria.

Comment: So, I got the same problem and also search on Doctrine Github. It's actual error of Doctrine and they fixed it. FYI: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4243